# Fetch external api in a loop. prev is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, nested-loops, fetch-api

So i'm trying to make a stock portfolio app and i'm at the stage of trying to get profit/loss on each order.

I have a loop where i loop through user orders and set the order ticker symbol to the stock API url. After I get the results from stock api, I get the latest close price of the stock, which would be todays date. I assign the current closing price as currentPrice and I set a new state where currentPrice is also listed.

I get these errors:

- [error response 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwkAJ.png)
- "Prev is not iterable" this comes from the setOrders state
- It loops way too many times. I just want it to loop for the length of orders array, which should be 4
- Sometimes i get info back, for example that TSLA current price is xxx and date xxx, but its quite random

This is my code.

```
const StockFetcher = (orderList, setOrders) => {

    //should do 4 cycles
    for(var i in orderList){
        if(orderList.length !== 0){
            //filter through orderList
            const ticker = orderList[i]['ticker']
            const price = orderList[i]['price']
            const amount = orderList[i]['amount']
            const date = orderList[i]['date']

            //fetch current order data
            axios.get(`${STOCK_API}&symbol=${ticker}&apikey=${TOKEN}`)
            .then(response => {
                const foo = JSON.stringify(response)

                if(response){
                    console.log("Response data: " + response.data)
                    const data = response.data
                    //var time = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
                    //const time = 2021-12-07
                    const todayDate = data['Time Series (Daily)']['2021-12-05']['4. close']

                    if(todayDate){
                        const currentPrice = todayDate

                        console.log(ticker + " Current price: " + currentPrice)

                        const stockInfo = {
                            ticker,
                            price,
                            amount,
                            date,
                            currentPrice
                        }
                        setOrders(prev =>[...prev, stockInfo])

                    }


                
                }else{
                    console.log("This symbol does not exist in the api")
                }
            }).catch(e =>{
                console.log("Something went wrong with StockFetcher" + e)
            })
        } else{
            console.log("There are no orderList to fetch :/")
            break;
        }

    }
  
}

export default StockFetcher
```

Im calling this code on another file.

This is the json i get from the api call:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-12-07 16:00:01",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2021-12-07": {
            "1. open": "331.6400",
            "2. high": "335.8000",
            "3. low": "330.1000",
            "4. close": "334.9200",
            "5. volume": "30718746"
        },
        "2021-12-06": {
            "1. open": "323.9500",
            "2. high": "327.4500",
            "3. low": "319.2300",
            "4. close": "326.1900",
            "5. volume": "30032556"
        },
        "2021-12-03": {
            "1. open": "331.9900",
            "2. high": "332.7000",
            "3. low": "318.0300",
            "4. close": "323.0100",
            "5. volume": "41779279"
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in do not use for…in statement instead use array.forEach or oldschool for loop.
You should also set initial value of orders to an empty array so that you can use prev as iterable.

Comment: Thanks, but i need the orderList to have items in it so I can iterate through it. So I would need to put the new data with currentPrice into a totally separate state right?

Any tips on how to improve performance or clean the code up? It's seems messy to me but I can't think of anything else. Maybe just divide the code up into smaller functions?

Comment: Are you trying to set state for each order list item? It seems you are fetching for each order kist item but updating the orders state from fetched item’s today’s property

Comment: yes, from the for loop I want to get the current price of the stock and then add to the stock the currenPrice value

Comment: So you need to use only the last item in your order list, no need to iterate through all items

Comment: i want to loop through them all to get the price change for all of them. This is what i'm trying to do : https://imgur.com/a/Kwd5vSL